# How do I append different table in multiple excel sheets with Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to send new data to a table in excel with data from python. I want to sort data from an excel book in python and depending on the result I want to send it to a specific sheet in another excel workbook. I can't seem to find a way to simply add data to the bottom of a table in excel without rewriting the table or specifying the exact coordinates of where the new data should go.

```py
file = open("reslts.cvs", "a")

file.write("\npizza, 12)
```

This worked perfectly apart from the fact that I can't send to different sheets this way.

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame([1, 4])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine= "openpyxl", mode='a') as writer:
    test_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

This is also close to woking but instead of appending the sheet it makes a new sheet with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

The helper function for appending DataFrame to existing Excel file sheet [[see the link]](https://pupli.net/2019/12/append-existing-excel-sheet-with-new-dataframe-using-python-pandas/):

```
import pandas as pd
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False, 
                       **to_excel_kwargs):
    """
    Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
    into [sheet_name] Sheet.
    If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

    Parameters:
      filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
                 (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
      df : dataframe to save to workbook
      sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                   (default: 'Sheet1')
      startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                 Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                 in the existing DF and write to the next row...
      truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                       before writing DataFrame to Excel file
      to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                        [can be dictionary]

    Returns: None
    """
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()
```

In your case:

```
fullPath        = "reslts.cvs"
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
test_df = pd.DataFrame([1, 4])
append_df_to_excel(fullPath, test_df, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

I have tested entire code and it is doing exactly what you would like to do. Best!

Comment: what should I put in the Square brackets "sheets[sheetname]"
    test_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=writer.sheets["Sheet1"].max_row)
KeyError: 'Sheet1'

Comment: import pandas as pd

fullPath = "Results.xlsx"
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
test_df = pd.DataFrame([1, 4])



def append_df_to_excel(fullPath, test_df, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False):

    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl').                                                      I have just copied that all in and I'm really not sure what I need to change and not change?

Comment: Have you tried the updated answer? It is tested without any issues based on your requirements,